# Get list of names of all files in a directory (Perl)

Tags: directory-structure, perl

What is the easiest way to get list of full names of all files in a given directory (including files in subdirectories)?

Yes, I know about `File::Find` module. But is there an easier way?

Comment: Define 'easiest'...

Comment: I don't think it gets any easier than `File::Find`, unless you can avoid Perl altogether and use a different tool, e.g., if you just wanted to know how much space these files take, you could use `du -hs` on Linux.

Comment: [Path::Tiny->iterator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#iterator)

Comment: Just so you know, `File::Find` very fast. Learn to use it if you need to iterate more than 10k files, unless speed isn't an issue. On my laptop, File::Find::Rule is 2-3x slower. Of course, if you're iterating over one directory, the difference is trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) is a very useful tool

```
perl -Mstrict -MFile::Find::Rule -wE'
    my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->in("."); 
    say for @files'
```

You can first get the object `my $ffr = File::Find::Rule` and then set rules on it. The rule `->file` only makes it not return directories, while it still recurses. There are many such "rules" to fine tune the behavior. I did find its performance slower under some conditions. See link at the end.

The core [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) does all that its wrapper above does, perhaps with just a little more work

```
perl -Mstrict -MFile::Find -wE' my @dirs = (@ARGV ? @ARGV : ".");
    my @files;
    find( sub { push @files, $File::Find::name if -f }, @dirs );
    say for @files;
' dir1 dir2 ...      (or pass nothing, to scan ".")
```

where only regular files are collected, by [`-f` filetest](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). I've added an example of how to (optionally) pass a directory list to scan in a one-liner.  It is still the best performing module as far as I know.  In some uses it can be considerably faster.

The [Path::Tiny->iterator](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm#iterator) is very nice as well, for "lazily" walking a tree

```
perl -Mstrict -MPath::Tiny -wE' my $dir = shift // ".";
    my $iter = path($dir)->iterator({recurse => 1}); 
    while (my $path = $iter->()) { say $path }'
```

where you can interrogate the encountered content in a number of ways and  conveniently.  The module has many other tools and uses for file-system work, this is almost a "side" feature.

The [Path::Iterator::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Iterator-Rule-1.012/lib/Path/Iterator/Rule.pm), also from the author of `Path::Tiny`, also offers lazy iterations but is a full, dedicated iterator, with the interface similar to `File::Find::Rule`

```
perl -Mstrict -MPath::Iterator::Rule -wE' my $dir = shift // "."; 
    my $rule = Path::Iterator::Rule->new->not_dir->not_empty; 
    my $next = $rule->iter($dir);
    while (my $file = $next->()) { say $file }
' dirname
```

One can set up rules with a *lot* of convenience methods, also including ones for logic, file content queries, custom-written rules, and more.

See a [performance comparison](https://rjbs.manxome.org/rubric/entry/1981) for a selection of file-finders (from 2013).